# Conditionally dry run a command block with BASH heredoc

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, debug

I wanted to have something as simple as that in my script:

```
set_dryrun()
{
    BEGIN='cat << EOF'
    END='EOF'
}

[ "$1" == "-dryrun" ] && set_dryrun

${BEGIN}
    ls -l
${END}
```

So that if I run it with the `-dryrun` parameter, commands between `${BEGIN}` and `${END}` would be just printed, but not executed.

Everything goes well if I run without the `-dryrun` flag:

```
$ ./dryrun_opt 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 arantesj arantesj 160 jan 25 17:15 dryrun_opt
```

With `-dryrun`, though, I see:

```
$ ./dryrun_opt -dryrun
cat: '<<': No such file or directory
cat: EOF: No such file or directory
-rwxrwxr-x 1 arantesj arantesj 160 jan 25 17:16 dryrun_opt
./dryrun_opt: line 14: EOF: command not found
```

Well... I am not replacing (expanding?) my heredoc correctly, I know, but how should I, if possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
set_dryrun()
{
    BEGIN='cat << EOF'
    END='EOF'
}

[ "$1" == "-dryrun" ] && set_dryrun

eval "${BEGIN}
    ls -l
${END}"
```

However, I suspect that this whole approach will break at some point, when the heredoc becomes more complex than `'ls -l'`.  If there were quoting or escaping going on inside that, it would need to be done carefully or an approach this simple is likely to break.

Borrowing from the wisdom of [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167746/how-to-assign-a-heredoc-value-to-a-variable-in-bash), you might find this approach interesting to consider:

```
if [ "$1" == "-dryrun" ]
then
        CMD="cat"
else
        CMD="bash"      # your preferred shell here
fi

WORK="$(cat <<'EOF'
# abc'asdf"
# $(dont-execute-this)
# foo"bar"''
ls -l
echo "$PATH"
echo "\$PATH"
EOF
)"

$CMD <<< "$WORK"
```

Comment: Great! It worked fine for my current needs, but I will keep in mind (and text) your advice. Thank you @Jim-L.